# Clearcase config spec for different selection rules per vob in view

Tags: clearcase

The team would like to perform their work with one webview (instead of a view for each vob).  `vob1` work should be done on main, whereas `vob2` work should be done on a different branch (`branch1` below). I am not sure what the conceptual problem is with my rules below.  I expected that since clearcase will match rules from top to bottom it would apply the selections for `vob1` I have specified.

The config Spec I tried will checkout files for vob1 on branch1 instead of main.

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element /vobs/vob1/* .../main/LATEST
element /vobs/vob1/* /main/LATEST
element * .../branch1/LATEST
element * /main/LATEST -mkbranch branch1
element * /main/0 -mkbranch branch1
load /vobs/vob1
load /vobs/vob2
```

Is my desired goal possible?  What is the error above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't hesitate to make a dynamic view in order to test your selection rules: you will see immediately if said selection matches what you need, without having to re-update your snapshot view.

Second, try element `/vobs/vob1/...` instead of `/vobs/vob1/*`: that will include the vob root folder itself.
See "Pattern" in the page "[`config_spec`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/config_spec.htm)".

Comment: My original config spec with your recommended update works great.  Thank you.